# PHP if statement to display divs only on first page of pagination Joomla 4

Tags: component, joomla-4.x

I've spent the past few days trying different variations of if statements to get this working but it's now driving me nuts.

What I'd like to do is show a series of divs on the first page of a custom component but not on any other pages 2, 3, etc.

I'm using Joomla 4 with the custom component.

This is my current code which is producing errors.

```
<?php if ($this->app->getInput()->getInt('start') < 1) : ?>
    Hello World
<?php : ?>
```

*edit* **More information**

For instance, the following code is to display items from the database in the component.

```
<div class="everistBlock featured">
            <?php $i = 0; foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : if ($i == 15) {break;} ?>
                <?php if ($item->articletype=="Featured Article") : ?>
                    <div class="featuredContainer">
                        <div class="newsItem"> 
                            <div class="newsItemImage">
                                <img src="<?php echo $item->articleimage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="newsItemTitle">
                                <a href="<?php echo Route::_('index.php?option=com_everist&view=newsarticle&id='.(int) $item->id); ?>"><?php echo $this->escape($item->title); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php $i++; endforeach ?>
        </div>
```

What I would like to do is have more like this but starting on page 2, or only visible on page 1.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you show also what error do you get?

Comment: It's just a blank page I get (white screen of death) on the specific page.

Comment: Did you turn on the error reporting and debug? If not, do it for see what error show up.

Comment: We need more information.  Is this admin or site?  Is this code in display tmpl file or the source view file?  I'll make some assumptions for the response below.

Comment: I've updated the question with further information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Pagination object rather than trying to derive it from the input variables.

In your HtmlView file:

```
$this->pagination = $this->get('pagination');
```

Then in your tmpl file, you can ask the pagination which page you're on:

```
if($this->pagination->pagesCurrent == 1) {
    //Do whatever you want for the first page
} else {
    //Alternative content for other pages
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!

Could I also ask, how can I reset the count. For instance, articles showing on page 1 - how would I get these to show on page 2 as well as if page 2 is the start.

Answer (score 0):

In the Source View file (src/View/HtmlView.php) you possibly have this in the display function:

```
$this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
```

Then in the multiples listing tmpl file you would have something like:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: This is to generate the pagination, not to create a control for what page something will appear on.